# Hide and show li active tags in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="product">
<ul id="shop">
<li> Vision </li>
<li class="active">Type</li>
<li> Energy</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to show only active li  tags ,while other li tags will be hide.

**Excepted Output will be**

**Type**

I try javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 
          $('#shop li.active').show();
            });
```

But nothing will happen..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery, you need to hide which are not active

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#shop li:not(.active)').hide();
  $('#shop li.active').show();
});
```

Can be done using CSS as well

```
#shop li:not(.active){
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show only active li tags ,while other li tags will be hide.

Hide the siblings

```
 $('#shop li.active').show().siblings().hide();
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#shop li.active').show().siblings().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product">
  <ul id="shop">
    <li> Vision </li>
    <li class="active">Type</li>
    <li> Energy</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> But nothing will happen..

Since there was no logic for hiding the `li`'s, only showing them. As shown above, you need to show the `active` ones and hide rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a little bit of css which will hide li tags by default

```
ul li{
  display:none
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jzj6o5ms/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.not` & `hide`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').not('.active').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product">
  <ul id="shop">
    <li> Vision </li>
    <li class="active">Type</li>
    <li> Energy</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```